# What can I put under a rug to minimize impact sounds?

Tags: noise-reduction

We want to minimize impact sounds for our downfloor neighbots from one room. The floor surface is laminate, we don't know how the exact build of the floor but assume it's wood since the house is >100 years old. Removing and redoing the existing floor is out of question. The idea is to use floor rugs with an underlay or pad for most of the room in question.

The first idea is to use cork mats (probably 5mm, maybe less), but I have serious doubts if they won't glide on the floor too much.

My problem is that so far every singe product advertised for impact sound attenuation is marketed as an underly for a carpet or laminate floor, not to put under a simple rug. So basically a product that attenuates impact sounds and doesnt slip.

So I'm looking for recommondations for an underlay - not product X, since what's availible near you might not be availible here. I'm looking for statements wether PVC fleece or cork or whatever has been used effectivly in this application.

I've edited the question from asking for specific experiences with cork to a more open question)

Comment: Why not just wear soft slippers instead of jackboots?

Comment: Don't tell me what to wear in my home!

Comment: Then I won’t make the mistake of telling you what to do in your home either.

Comment: Cork will attenuate sound as will most carpet padding. I have found the “foam” style sheet material designed to be placed under laminate flooring to hold up the best and it may be less expensive than cork. If the issue is hard sole shoes the impact will be attenuated but squeak/creaky flooring may not be reduced much as that is due to the point loading.

Comment: I suspect a carpet pad (there are ones specifically claimed to help with sound transmission - a bit denser/firmer than average) would likely cost less (last time I looked at cork I was aghast at the prices and I suspect it's only gotten worse) as well as suit the actual use case better (*i.e.* not slipping around.)

Comment: thx, will look further for carpet pads with sound attenuation.